# android studio: texview don't show

Tags: android, textview

I have some trouble with my texview, when I use m button in my first activity I want to open I second activity and display my texview with a information that I get from my first activity. But when I use `ID.setText(intent_nom.getStringExtra("nom"));` my application doesn't work anymore. Can you help me please, thanks.

here my first activity

```
package com.maze.maze;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup radiogroup;
    Button button_val;
    EditText e_prenom;
    EditText e_nom;
    private static final String SAVED_TEXT_KEY = "some_key";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_val=findViewById(R.id.button_v);
        radiogroup=findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        e_prenom=findViewById(R.id.e_prenom);
        e_nom=findViewById(R.id.e_nom);




        button_val.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override


            public void onClick(View view){

                int  laby =0;
                switch (radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
                {
                    case R.id.radio_1: laby=1; break;
                    case R.id.radio_2: laby=2; break;
                    case R.id.radio_3: laby=3; break;
                    case R.id.radio_4: laby=4; break;
                    case R.id.radio_5: laby=5; break;
                }
                Intent intent_laby= new Intent();
                intent_laby.putExtra("num_labyrinth",laby);
                Intent intent_nom= new Intent();
                intent_nom.putExtra("nom", e_nom.getText() );
                Intent intent_prenom= new Intent();
                intent_prenom.putExtra("prenom", e_prenom.getText() );
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_labyrinth.class));
            }

        });

    }




}
```

here my second activity

```
package com.maze.maze;
import java.io.InputStream;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity_labyrinth extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ID=findViewById(R.id.ID);

        Intent intent_nom  = getIntent();
        ID.setText(intent_nom.getStringExtra("nom"));


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_labyrinth);
    }
}
```

here my the xml file of my second activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".Activity_labyrinth"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ID"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: put your code below to setContentView().

Comment: In second activity  set your text after  setContentView(R.layout.activity_labyrinth);

Answer (score 0):

You are making a new `Intent` when starting the new activity. Try this in your click listener where you are starting `Activity_labyrinth`:

```
Intent intent_nom = new Intent();
intent_nom.putExtra("nom", e_nom.getText() );
startActivity(intent_nom);
```

Comment: As @Mustufa Ansari pointed out, put `setContentView(R.layout.activity_labyrinth);` directly below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and then set the text.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 4 different intent variable and at last start activity without any data.
You can use below code to start activity,

```
Intent intent_laby= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_labyrinth.class);
  intent_laby.putExtra("num_labyrinth",laby);
  intent_laby.putExtra("nom", e_nom.getText() );
  intent_laby.putExtra("prenom", e_prenom.getText() );
  startActivity(intent_laby);
```

Hope it will help!!

Comment: Thank, now the second activity open but nothing is written on the textView even if a just put a basic string(without recovering any data from the first application )

Comment: you need to call setContentView(R.layout.activity_labyrinth); first then find your view and set your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code showing that

1. you want to pass data form an activity to another activity.
2. Here you use Intent.

So you should set data with that Intent what you start.

**Problem 1:** You are assigning data with wrong Intent object.

```
Intent intent_nom= new Intent();
intent_nom.putExtra("nom", e_nom.getText());
startActivity(intent_nom);
```

**Problem 2:** You should send String data because you are receiving data by  `getStringExtra("nom")`.

```
Intent intent_nom= new Intent();
intent_nom.putExtra("nom", e_nom.getText().toString());//Here need this
startActivity(intent_nom);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You are creating total four intent and 3 intents with values and the last one to start the activity, you don't need to do that, only one intent is capable of sending values and navigating from one activity to another.

> ```
> Intent intent_laby= new Intent();
>                 intent_laby.putExtra("num_labyrinth",laby);
>
>                 intent_laby.putExtra("nom", e_nom.getText().toString() );
>
>                 intent_laby.putExtra("prenom", e_prenom.getText().toString() );
>                 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_labyrinth.class));
> ```

Also, note that you need to call `toString()` when sending values from edit text.

2. In `Activity_labyrinth` `setContentView` should be called before `findViewById`, so you code should be:

> ```
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_labyrinth);
> ID=findViewById(R.id.ID);
>
>         Intent intent_nom  = getIntent();
>         ID.setText(intent_nom.getStringExtra("nom"));
> ```

Comment: I don’t see how to use toString() to send data. Can I have a exemple please

Comment: @tess, It's already in the answer, In e_nom.getText().toString()  and e_prenom.getText().toString()

Comment: @tess you just need to replace the code from the answer to your project, let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Activity Life-Cycle, OnCreate Need To SetContentView(View), After You Can Use Your XML Widgets.

You Getting TextView Without SetConentView, Need To Set Your XML View (Bind With Your Activity) Your Activity Using SetConentView().

You Can Write Code As Below :

```
public class Activity_labyrinth extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_labyrinth);

        ID=findViewById(R.id.ID);

        Intent intent_nom  = getIntent();
        ID.setText(intent_nom.getStringExtra("nom"));

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_labyrinth);
        //Move This Line Below TextView Casting 
    }
}
```